# Salesforce - Querying to fetch data from junction object and Accounts

Tags: salesforce

I have a junction object called "*JIRA_Data*" and its linked/ related to Accounts. How do I query to fetch data from this relationship. I am trying to extract id,type from Account object and Name from JIRA_Data junction object.

Could anyone assist. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could do it multiple ways depending on how you want the data. If you query it from the parent account it would be something to the effect:

```
SELECT Id, Name, (Select ID, Name, Other_Parent__r.Name FROM Jira_Datas__r) FROM Account
```

or from the junction

```
SELECT Id, Name, Account.Name, Other_Parent__r.Name FROM Jira_Data__c
```